# Cannot get data with curl

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I try to get data with curl and I run the query in this way:

```
curl -XGET '<ip>:9200/info-2019.08.21/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name" : "TP-01"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "_all",
            "query": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

But I get this response but no data return

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
```

but I have check the index with the curl command  as below,

```
curl -XGET '<ip>:9200/info-2019.08.21/_search?pretty'
```

I can get  the record as below,

```
{
    "_index" : "info-2019.08.21",
    "_type" : "customer",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "TP-01",
      "geoip" : {
        "country" : "US",
        "city" : "NY",
        "long" : 125.683899,
        "lat" : 25.1469,
        "coordinates" : [
          125.683899,
          25.1469
        ]
      },
      "name" : "TP-01"
    }
  }
]
```

}

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add some space around `-H`

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index?

Comment: guessing it's the result of the standard analyzer removing the hyphen. Try changing your query to use the keyword field: `"name.keyword": "TP-01"`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you an exact answer without seeing the index mapping, but I can guess two things:

1. Name might be a text field. As you can see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#avoid-term-query-text-fields), a term query is a bad choice for a text field, since the text field has some standard analyzers. Change your query to aa match query and it should work
2. What version of ES are you using? I believe the `_all` field has been [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/mapping-all-field.html) since ES 6. I'm not sure what the end goal is of your second query part, but to search all fields you can just leave this part away, or use a wildcard as the default field.

So for my setup and without custom mapping, your query could look like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": "TP-01"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```